# Logical operators and wrong result in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, logic

I got the x and y by a UITapGestureRecognizer set on the screen, after having obtained the location I find the object touched, so I put the conditions, but does not work. Maybe I put the wrong conditions in objective C? Xcode gives no errors but the function does not work.

```
  -(void)tappedMapOniPad:(int)x andy:(int)y{
       NSLog(@"the x is: %d", x);
         //the x is: 302
       NSLog(@"the y is: %d", y);
         //the y is: 37

       if((121<x<=181) && (8<y<=51)){ //the error is here
            self.stand = 431;
        }else if ((181<x<=257) && (8<y<=51)){
            self.stand=430;
        }else if ((257<x<=330) && (8<y<=51)){
            self.stand = 429;
        }

      NSLog(@"The stand is %d", self.stand);
        //The stand is 431

   }
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
if((121<x<=181) && (8<y<=51))
```

by

```
if((121 < x && x <= 181) && (8 < y && y <= 51))
```

Comment: You can even reorganize parethesis this way : `if((121 < x) && (x <= 181) && (8 < y) && (y <= 51))`

Comment: Yes, I assumed that OP had some logic behind grouping the first two conditions together, so it might be better to keep it that way.

Answer (score 5):

```
121<x<=181
```

let's assume  x := 10 `121<10<=181` -> `false<=181` -> `0<=181` -> true

you have to do it step by step.

```
((121 < x) &&  (x <=181))
```

let's assume  x := 10 `((121 < 10) &&  (10 <=181))` ->`false && true` ->`false`

Answer (score 1):

`(121<x<=181)` kind of expression is invalid in Obj-c.

Use, `(x>121 && x<=181)`

Your full code will be like :

```
    if((x>121 && x<=181) && (y>8 && y<=51)){ //the error is here
        self.stand = 431;
    }
    else if ((x>181 && x<=257) && (y>8 && y<=51)){
        self.stand=430;
    }
    else if ((x> 255 && x<=330) && (y>8 && y<=51)){
        self.stand = 429;
    }
```

Or you can optimize it as:

```
if(y>8 && y<=51){
    if (x> 257 && x<=330) {
        self.stand = 429;
    }
    else if(x>181){
        self.stand=430;
    }
    else if(x>121){
        self.stand = 431;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing `&&`

Try

```
if((121<x&&x <=181)&&(8<y&&y <=51))
```

Hope it helps